# How to increase the ID value in the code below

Tags: java

```
public class Student {
private String Last_Name;
private String First_Name;
private int Grade_Level, ID;
private double GPA;

public Student() {
    Last_Name = "None";
    First_Name = "None";
    Grade_Level = 0;
    GPA = 0.0;
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel, double gpa) {
    Last_Name = lastName;
    First_Name = firstName;
    Grade_Level = gradeLevel;
    GPA = gpa;
}

public String toString(){
    return Last_Name + ", " + First_Name + "\nGPA: " + GPA + "\nGrade Level: " + Grade_Level + " id # " + ID++;
}
```

}

I know each time when the main function is calling the ID value, it will initialize it again and again to 0, I've thought about using the for loop but it doesn't work, so how to fix that, thank you very much for your help!
Here is the sample run:

```
None, None
GPA: 0.0
Grade Level: 0 id # 1

None, None
GPA: 0.0
Grade Level: 0 id # 2


None, None
GPA: 0.0
Grade Level: 0 id # 3

Dovi, Mrs.
GPA: 3.4
Grade Level: 7 id # 4
```

Comment: Java always initializes ints to 0. You never assigned anything to `ID`. If you want it to have a different value, then you must assign to it.

Comment: @dsh, "*Java always initializes ints to 0*" if they are not local variables

Comment: Technically, yes, locals are not initialized with default values but that is only because the compiler will force the programmer to initialize the local variable.  ([Java Language Specification, Section 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5))

Comment: Appreciate you guys, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely looking for a shared variable between instances that doesn't change its state regardless of an amount of already created objects. This is what static members do:

```
private static int id;
```

Comment: @BaronZhu, it's not a type, just a keyword that makes a variable *global* for the whole class

Comment: feel free to mark this as the answer if it fixed your problem in order to close the question @BaronZhu